# Visual Studio and Resharper and Symbol Completion

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

In Intellij or Eclipse, when I start typing a class that I haven't imported yet, I will get suggestions.  For example if I type 'Lis' I will most likely get a load of suggestions of various List classes that are in my classpath.  If I don't know how to spell the class properly or don't know exactly what I'm after I can work it out quickly just by typing.  In VS 2012 even with Resharper, I can't reproduce this behavior.  It really does make a difference, is it not possible in VS?

Comment: I get similar this behavior with R#, for example if I type List, i get SortedList, ArrayList, etc, however those namespaces need to be already imported using 'using' keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the [Import Symbol Completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Type_Name.html) feature for this.

Just write part of the name (or camel case initials) and press: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (VS shortcuts) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (IntelliJ shortcuts)

This works even for types/symbols whose namespaces have not yet been imported (ReSharper will add them).

Comment: I guess it has "Starts with" behavior... If I type List and then use Shift+Alt+Space I see all classes starting with List, but not "SortedList"

Comment: @SebastianK yes, it's a kind of "Starts with" behavior. But I find the camel case feature very handy. For example, if you type `slis` and do shift+alt+space it will show `SortedList`